# How do I send message to specific client in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I send message to specific client ?,is it possible that I can send only message to a specific client in node.js ?

```
var net = require('net');

var clients = [];

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

   clients.push(socket);

   var message = "message to client";


   //here how to send to a specific client ?   

});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing a lot of context.  You're already keeping an array of connections in the `clients` array (though you need to know when they disconnect).  So, use whatever logic you want to select a particular socket from the clients array and send some data over that socket.

Comment: @jfriend00, no I did not say that  when they disconnected, I want to send to a particular client , just like skype we can send message to a specific friend

Comment: My point about the disconnect is that you need to be updating your `clients` array when a socket disconnects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear exactly what you're trying to do, but you are already keeping a list of sockets in the `clients` array so you just need to apply whatever logic fits your need to select one of those sockets and then use `.write()` to write some data on that socket:

```
var net = require('net');
var clients = [];
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
   clients.push(socket);
   var message = "message to client";

   // pick a socket from the array using whatever logic you want and send to it
   clients[0].write(msg);
});
```